# Ternary Operator for Advanced Custom Fields

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, ternary-operator, advanced-custom-fields

I have been creating my own WP themes using Advanced Custom Fields extensively and I continue to type code out like:

```
<?php
if(get_field('featured_courses_heading_text', 'option')) {
    echo get_field('featured_courses_heading_text', 'option');
}
?>
```

Is there a more condensed version of this code I could use with Ternary Operators? I tried looking at the documentation but couldnt find anything

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just do this which will do the same thing, since you have no alternate value to output.

```
<?php echo get_field('featured_courses_heading_text', 'option'); ?>
```

But if you were doing an if else then you could do this which will output the value if it doesn't evaluate to nothing (false) `null, <empty string>, 0, false`

```
<?php echo get_field('featured_courses_heading_text', 'option') ?: 'nothing here'; ?>
```

Would be the same as

```
<?php if(get_field('featured_courses_heading_text', 'option')) { echo get_field('featured_courses_heading_text', 'option'); } else { echo 'nothing here'; }  ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure why you need a Ternary Operator; I think your code is fine.

```
<?php 
    echo get_field('featured_courses_heading_text', 'option') ?: '';
?>
```

Comment: Note that this works only in PHP 5.3 or higher: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php#language.operators.comparison.ternary

Comment: @TimoSta, you are right, but I hope that's what the author of the question is using.